# Wrong C output in terminal

Tags: c, turbo-c

So I was experimenting with arrays in C and came across this weird event where the value of an array changes even though I am not manipulating the data of the elements in that array.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main () {
    int arr[] = {0};

    scanf("%i", &arr[0]);
    scanf("%i", &arr[1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("value of i %i\n", i);
        printf("%i\n", arr[i]);
    }

    getch();
}
```

and the output was:

```
2 //this is an input
3 //this is an input
value of i 0
2
value of i 1
1
```

I have the same code in Turbo C but in Turbo C the value of the elements in that array is correct, the output in Turbo is is:

```
2 //this is an input
3 //this is an input
value of i 0
2
value of i 1
3
```

I tried to debug and see when does the change of value happens in the code, so I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main () {
    int arr[] = {0};

    scanf("%i", &arr[0]);
    scanf("%i", &arr[1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("value of i %i\n", i);
        printf("%i\n", arr[i]);
    }

    printf("%i\n", arr[0]);
    printf("%i\n", arr[1]);

    getch();
}
```

and now the output is very weird:

```
2 //this is an input
3 //this is an input
value of i 0
2
value of i 1
1
2
2
```

Comment: it's intentional because I want the array to be dynamic

Comment: which is not the way to define a dynamic array. `arr[1]` is the value next to your arr, and in fact it's a segmentation fault

Comment: okay thanks I will try that tomorrow, I'm too tired to code atm LMAO

Comment: Your code has 'undefined behavior'. You try to write to the second element of an array of size = 1

Answer (score 0):

`arr[1]` is not initialised. Try,
`int arr[] = {0, 0};`

Comment: In fact, it's not that `arr[1]` is not initialised, it's because `arr[1]` is the "memory case" next to `arr`

Comment: c doesn't automatically append to arrays. You can make it dynamic by using malloc, but you still need to know how big to make it. If you don't know at the start how long the list is to be, use a linked list. Thanks user3121023 for the support. My original answer was good.

Comment: Arr[1] does not exist, it's not that it's not initialized. Arr has only one element. Your code makes a 2 element array

Comment: @user3121023, it doesn't answer the question, OP was talking about dynamic allocation, and want to know why trying to increase the size of his array doesnt work properly. Answer: because it's not how dynamically allocated array and memory work in C. Thus it doesn't answer the question, and `arr[]` is a misleading notation to begin with

Comment: You're right about the dynamic aspect